# French culinary terminology for dicing vegetables

Tags: french-cuisine, dicing

The French language has many specific words for cooking.  What is the term used for food which is diced into tiny pieces?

Answer (score 3):

The name depends on the sice of the dices. There are:

- Brunoise as the smallest one with up to 1.5 mm
- Jardiniere ~5 mm
- Macédoine 5 to 7 mm
- Parmentier 0.8 to 1 cm
- Carré ~2cm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_culinary_knife_cuts

Comment: What the difference between Jardiniere and Mecédoine?

Comment: It seems Mecédoine can be slightly larger

Comment: Did you mean to type "8 to 1"? Seems like maybe that's a typo, but I couldn't find a reference in your link to confirm that.. If it's not a typo then please consider swapping the order of the numbers.

Comment: @Kat: The units were mixed up. It was 8mm to 1cm. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

From the French version of the [aforementioned page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupe_(cuisine)), the techniques are:

- *en julienne* : vegetables are cut in thin striped
- *en dés* : this results in cube-like pieces
- *en allumettes* : the result should be similar to matches (hence the name). While the *julienne* just means "stripes", *en allumettes* requires the pieces to be parallelipipedic.

Preparations are named according to their ingredients:

- *macedoine* is a colorful preparation of with legumes cut *en dés* (approximately 0.5cm)
- *brunoise* means vegetables or fruits are cut *en dés* of around 2cm each
- *mirepoix* is a combination of carrots, onion and celeriac

Comment: I believe you mean celery rather than celeriac in your definition of *mirepoix*.

Comment: Also, some terms are quite illustrative: "dés" means dices, "allumettes" means "matches".